# How to design asynchronous LIFO?

Tags: design, fifo, rtl

Is it possible to design asynchronous LIFO ( i.e. LIFO with different READ and WRITE clock)

In FIFO , we need to change the write address pointer only on wr_clk while in LIFO we need to change the write_address pointer on both wr_clk and rd_clk. Hence in my opinion we can't design a async LIFO ?

Comment: I would approach this from the other side: A system which requires an asynchronous LIFO would need revisiting the design decisions/parameters.

Comment: Why would you need an async LIFO? Is there anything wrong with cascading an async FIFO and a sync LIFO or similar? Or is this purely a theoretical question?

Comment: purely a theoretical question

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to show that you cannot design an asychronous FIFO that you can **prove** never re-orders data.

The problem is the distinction between the last data pushed, and the data currently being pushed. If a simultaneous pop occurs, which data does it return?

In a synchronous FIFO, you cannot get a simultaneous pop and push *by design*. They simply cannot exist. When you have two asynchronous clock domains, it is possible.

There are two considerations. One is can you crash the logic? The other is can you define what you mean by 'correct order' for inputs and outputs.

Whether you can crash the logic is a well-studied problem, metastability, and there's both good and bad news. The bad news news is that it's impossible to completely rule out crashing the logic. The good news is that, with proper design, you can make the possibility of a crash very small, and by adding extra logic in one latch increments, you can further reduce the probability exponentially, until it becomes likely you'll never see a crash in the age of the universe.

The solution for metastability works well with a FIFO, when correct order is defined in each clock domain exclusively, and only the timing of the correct datum being emitted is uncertain. Unfortunately, in a LIFO, correct order is defined across the domains. When you come to test whether your LIFO works, you can create simultaneous push/pop to within 10nS tolerance, or to within 1nS, or to within 10pS (if you have fast enough logic), but you can never create a reproducible 'simultaneous', and so never prove whether your LIFO is working or not.

However, if you accept that in near-simultaneous push/pop situations that sometimes data order may be switched from what you expected, it is possible to design logic that is unlikely to fail.

When faced with metastability, designers often set about chasing their tails to try to decide whether metastability is happening, and if so, block until it has resolved. Unfortunately, all attempted solutions of this type end up simply moving the metastability problem, not solving it. They create a Gordian Knot of extra logic gates that can be difficult to navigate. Alexander's Sword (Occam's Razor) is to note that with asynchronous domains, metastability *always* occurs, and you might as well face the problem of specification head on.

A one-paragraph primer on metastability, to save you chasing references. Consider two edges 1uS apart. You need logic with an order of 1MHz bandwidth to resolve them. Now sweep the edge timing from +1uS through to -1uS. When they're 1nS apart, you need 1GHz bandwidth. As they approach coincidence, you approach needing an infinite bandwidth, which you can never have. Your finite bandwidth logic will settle exponentially, so you need to wait for it to resolve. Every one extra time constant you wait, it will resolve a further proportion of initial conditions, so the unresolved proportion falls exponentially. If it doesn't resolve in the time you've allowed, then you can get the crash.

It's worth looking at how other logic types deal with the problem of asynchronous timing. Let's look at latches, FIFOs and dual-port RAMs.

Latches specify a setup and hold time. If the data and clock transition closer than these, the behaviour is unspecified.

With FIFOs, the specification uncertainty is whether the new data comes out this clock, or the next one, which is rarely a problem.

You could consider a dual-port RAM to be a collection of addressable one-deep LIFOs. Usually the asynchronous ports nature is to avoid logic crashes if simultaneous accesses occur, as data integrity is usually handled by their use a ping-pong buffers, reading rarely occurs at the same address writing is happening. Should a single location be hit with both a read and a write at the same time, then the tautologous 'write completed' concept comes into play. Good luck with specifying which data you get ahead of time.

With a LIFO, it's the logic data order that's at issue, which is likely to be a killer.

Comment: A LIFO is **supposed** to reorder data; the problem is defining what the **correct** output data order should be. And this is fundamentally unresolvable in the asynchronous case, as you say.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATED:

Answer - STILL "yes" in a practical real world.

> Is it possible to design asynchronous LIFO ( i.e. LIFO with different READ and WRITE clock)

The key issue is what action to take when "essentially simultaneous" write completion and read signals occur. The key related 'problem' is deciding the tolerances on "essentially simultaneous".

If you are willing to have a decision of "which happened first" - write-completion or read request made by the LIFO system based on its processing of the applied R and W signals internally, then, yes, it is possible.

In borderline cases you are making "space-time related decisions. EM  waves travel at about 1 foot per nanosecond in vacuum and art various slower speeds in other me. So, the meaning of "first" depends in limiting cases on where you measure waveforms. The actual circuitry is not usually built with timing relationships relative to some fixed physical point in the system.

If you are going to enter states of existential angst over which came first, with resolutions of microseconds or nanoseconds or picoseconds, or .... and with the reference point within the system defined as some real-world-irrelevant location then 
 it will never be possible to establish 'which signal came first' with perfect accuracy. .

Instead, 
You need to define rules to govern what happens under all conditions / states. Presumably "clock" refers to a write or read request signal and does not assume a fixed cycle boundary on which reads or writes must fall.

> In FIFO , we need to change the write address pointer only on wr_clk
>   while in LIFO we need to change the write_address pointer on both
>   wr_clk and rd_clk. Hence in my opinion we can't design a async LIFO ?

You need to decide whether input or output can "block" for one (or more) clock cycles if conflict situations occur.

If blocking is disallowed you need to decide how to handle data that is presented or requested when some other action makes it unavailable.
Some "philosophy" is required in deciding whether it is ever acceptable for data to become disordered and, if not, how to handle the consequences.

You need to decide how to handle situations which are notionally at least "impossible" to handle correctly. eg if a read request occurs during a write and blocking is not allowed do you serve the last completed written data (which isn't really the last data) or wait until the current write is completed? The former disorders the data read. The latter delays reading, and if there are multiple sequential writes a read may be delayed indefinitely.

Defining "last in" as "last completed write" overcomes many of the above issues.

You very probably have to decide "what to do with data" that is temporarily "in limbo".
eg if a write occurs during a read you could store it in the next empty location or in a buffer register and when the read completes, disable the usual post read pointer move or allow it and then move the read pointer to the location just vacated, and in either case move the new data from the buffer to the location just located.

Drawing a "truth table" of all possible states (not very many) and appropriate actions should make the task "not too hard".

Comment: unfortunately, metastability means you can't decide whether you have to block or not! Any attempt to set a conflict time that works takes you back to either a synchronous system, or one that's metastable *somewhere*.

Comment: @Neil_UK So do YOU say 'impossible" or "possible with the following rules". eg IF "Last In" means "last COMPLETED write at time of a read then the reordering is allowable by definition. What do you see as fatally fatal in practice?

Comment: Read my answer. I make a disctintion between crashing the logic, and proving that the order is correct. The problem is proof. The only way that's **possible** to define what the last COMPLETED push was is to see what comes out when you pop, which is a tautology. I maintain that because of metastability, it's not possible in practice, or in theory, to align a test generator to demonstrate whether it's working under all conditions. It's only possible to say that with alignment up to T tolerance, it works, and we have to accept either order as valid when less than this tolerance.

Comment: ... which means that, if we allow undefined behaviour when push/pop timing separation is smaller than some tolerance (rather like the tsu/th specs for flip flops) we are implicitly asking for a relation between the clock domains, which is essentially falling back to a synchronous, and not asynchronous system. In a fully asynchronous system, the system is no more provable for correctness than for a flip flop with fully asynchronous clock and data.